# attachment button doesnt work in OS mobile

Tags: css, iphone

I have a css class for adding an attachment.

But in IOS mobile you can't trigger the attachement button.

ANd only in the IOS mobile version it doesnt work.

This is the class:

```
.conversation-compose .photo i {
  display: block;
  color: #7d8488;
  font-size: 24px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

So what I have to change on this class?

Thank you

and this is the js code behind it:

```
  $('body').on('click', '.photo', function () {
       $('#upload-input')
            .val('') //remove old value so onchange can be triggered when same file is selected
            .click();
    });
```

Comment: what does not work? Depending on your "IOS Mobile"-Device, you might need a -webkit- prefix for transform. Try adding this line: -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

Comment: You cant trigger the button. SO nothing happens in IOS mobile

Comment: On the iphone oke

Comment: Can you make a js fiddle with the button? providing all the html, css and javascript necessary to reproduce the issue

Comment: Oke, will try, but it is very big

Comment: You don't have to provide your full code. Just the js, html and css needed to reproduce the issue

Comment: oke, yes, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/SavantKing/pqfd07cj/1/

Comment: YOu see it? Tim

Comment: Yes, I tested on an Iphone 6s and I was able to click the button

Comment: can you show the css here. I mean for not misunderstanding

Comment: YOu mean with this: -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

Comment: Then it works. So what you suggested? That will be very nice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199627/discussion-between-tim-gerhard-and-mightycode-newton).

Comment: Hi Tim, solved. See the solution. Very strange solution. But it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my.... this was the trick:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

What?? on a mobile you have a pointer??

Realy strange that you have to do that on a ipone.

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all but I'm glad you could resolve the issue! :)

Comment: Yes, I know. I also didn't had expected that! But it works :).